# Load Apache Logs from a Docker Container (Fargate) into Clowdwatch

Tags: apache, docker, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I have a Docker image, that loads a site at port 80 using Apache. The error logs are setup on apache.conf:

`ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`

The docker images is loaded in a cluster with fargate using a task definition.
I want to expose that file (or the errors in it) to AWS cloudwatch.

How do you setup the aws (or the docker image) for that?